# Rails unit tests without db setup or teardown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd, abstract-class, readonly

I want to write a few unit tests that do not make any changes to a database.

I have a Rails 2.3.11 application.  This app has a SQLite database as its primary database.  In many ways, this is a run-of-the-mill Rails app.

What makes this app unique is that it also establishes a connection to a SQL Server database.  I have some models which are abstract classes and they use the SQL Server database.  I have `before_save` and `before_destroy` callbacks to prevent any changes being made to the SQL Server database.  Also, the user credentials to connect to SQL Server are supposed to be read-only.

I would like to write unit tests that make assertions on the data that is already present in the SQL Server database.  But I don't want to setup or teardown the SQL Server database.

I am afraid to just see what happens.  I would like to have a setting in the unit test that will prevent Rails from trying to setup or teardown the SQL Server database.  Is this possible? How do I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I would like to use the same SQL Server database connection in Test environment as I use in Development environment, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup/tear down only affects the application database (SQLite, sounds like), not additional, external database connections.

Also, you should keep your test environment completely separate from your production environment. So, if you're using a test SQLServer DB as well (and you should be, with test data in it - not the production one) then you should be fine even if the worst happens.

Comment: So I have nothing to worry about, correct?  And there are 2 SQL Server database instances: production and development.  There isn't a 3rd SQL Server database instance for testing.  I want to use the development SQL Server db in the test environment.

Comment: If that SQLServer DB is completely outside your app, then you should be fine. If you're concerned about it (or maybe there's something important that you've left out of your question), you should create a test DB that cannot be harmed. For example, many of our production apps use their own application PostgreSQL DB, but also rely on an Oracle DB that handles user authentication that is technically not part of the Rails app. Rather than have our test/development environment touch the production Oracle DB, we have a test version of the Oracle DB running so we don't break production on accident.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will see if server team will create another SQL Server db instance just for test suite.